# 5G BER vs SNR for QPSK, 16QAM, 64QAM

Tags: matlab, noise, modulation, snr

Recently been running simulations where I run through simulating passing random data bits through LDPC Encoding, Modulation (4, 16 or 64) and then AWGN. The code itself is 90% developed by myself with the remaining 10% coming from a LDPC Encoder for 5G from Github (I mainly used this because the nrLDPCEncode function doesn't allow you to freely change the code rate).

The problem I am encountering is with my 16QAM and 64QAM modulation schemes. When running the simulations using these modulation schemes the results give a rather high SNR for 1e-2 BER. On one of my graphs below you can see the QPSK is a very steep waterfall curve ending at 1e-5 errors for around 2dB of SNR - as expected - whereas the 16 and 64 QAM ends closer to 13dB (possibly goes on further but haven't simulated that high due to taking so long). I'd expect to see the 16 and 64 QAM to end anywhere from 4dB up to 10dB however this clearly isn't the case.

If anyone could take a look at my code and see what my be the obvious problem, or if they have knowledge of 5G and could guess where I might need to look within my own code to help fix this problem that would be a big help! I would be open to using a different LDPC Encoder if that is the problem but at the moment I cannot find one that codes efficiently and allows me to change the Code Rate freely.

[image: Graph]

Here is the code I use to simulate the link and plot the graph.

```
    tic 
if ~isdeployed
    addpath('./codes');
end

% Constellation size and modulation schemes
M = {4,16,64};
modstring = {'QPSK', '16QAM', '64QAM'};

% LDPC config
blkSize = 256; % 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192
codeRate = '1/3'; % 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 5/6 

% Get LDPC struct
LDPC = ldpcGet_VariableModulation(blkSize, codeRate);

% Simulation parameters
snr_values = -2:0.1:15;
numIter = 1e3;

% Initialize arrays
%snr_values = zeros(size(ebno_range));
bit_errors = zeros(length(snr_values), numIter, length(M));

%% Simulate

for k = 1:length(M)
    for p = 1:length(snr_values)
        for i = 1:numIter

            % Generate random data
            data = randi([0 1], 1, LDPC.numInfBits);

            % Encode
            dataEnc = ldpcEncode(data, LDPC);

            % Add extra bits to ensure input equals number of bits per symbol
            z =mod(length(dataEnc),12);
            x = zeros(1,z);
            dataEnc_12 = cat(2,dataEnc,x);       
           
            % QAM mapping
            dataMod = qammod(dataEnc_12(:), M{k}, 'InputType', 'bit', 'UnitAveragePower', true);

            % AWGN
            dataRx = awgn(dataMod, snr_values(p));

            % LLR demapping
            dataLlr = qamdemod(dataRx, M{k}, 'OutputType', 'approxllr', 'UnitAveragePower', true);

            % Remove extra bits 
            dataLlr_cut = dataLlr(1:end-z);

            % Decode
            dataHat = ldpcDecode(dataLlr_cut', LDPC);

            % Count number of bit errors
            [~, bit_errors(p, i, k)] = biterr(data, dataHat);
        end
    end
end

%% Plot the results
figure;
colorstring = ['b', 'm', 'g'];
for k = 1:length(M)
    avg_BER = mean(bit_errors(:, :, k), 2);
    semilogy(snr_values, avg_BER, '.','DisplayName', modstring{k}, 'Color', colorstring(k));
    hold on;
    
    % Plot trendlines
    p = polyfit(snr_values, log10(avg_BER),2);
    fitted_curve = 10.^polyval(p, snr_values);
    semilogy(snr_values, fitted_curve, 'DisplayName',[modstring{k} ' TrendLine'],'LineWidth',1.5, 'Color',colorstring(k));
end

xlabel('SNR (dB)');
ylabel('Bit Error Rate (BER)');
title('BER vs SNR');
legend('Location', 'best');
grid on;
```

If anyone has any pointers or ideas on how to help or where I should investigate then that would be a big help. I would be happy to change the LDPC encoder or use another but it needs to be efficient and allow me to change the code rate freely. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I don't have matlab to test it. Is your constellation is not Gray coded? Could you include the constellation plot? Does the AWGN changes the constellation causing a mismatch when you pass to quamdec expecting unit energy? Could you include the BER before LDPC decoding? Did you try to pass the NoiseVariance to quamdec and use llr instead of approxllr? Do you know if your LDPC decoder is minsum or sumproduct? sumproduct decoders behavior changes when the LLR scale is changed.